# Problema con SVG y JSON en React

Tags: reactjs

rested.credits.for.you[.................................]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que en `fetchJson()` estas pasando un string como prop, este contiene solo el nombre del archivo JSON, para solucionarlo podrías tener los iconos en tu proyecto en una carpeta `'src/assets'` por ejemplo, y en el JSON en la propiedad `"icon"` tener la ruta a las imágenes partiendo desde el directorio raíz, o bien tener un pequeño archivo Icons.jsx con varios exports que contengan las rutas a todos los iconos con sus referencias.

Icons.jsx:

```
export const downarrow = "src/assets/downarrow.svg" // contiene las rutas a los iconos
export const clock = "src/assets/clock.svg"
export const addcircle = "src/assets/lightning.svg"
export const lightning = "src/assets/addcircle.svg"
export const notfound = "src/assets/notfound.svg"
```

Menu.json:

```
[
  {
    "icon": "downarrow",
    "title": "godown"
  },
  {
    "icon": "clock",
    "title": "watch"
  },
  {
    "icon": "addcircle",
    "title": "fast"
  },
  {
    "icon": "lightning",
    "title": "add"
  },{
    "title": "somenotfoundedicon",
    "icon": "xxxxxx"
  }
]
```

en FetchJson.jsx hacemos un `import * as Icons`, esto nos devolverá un objeto con todos los export (las referencias a las rutas) del archivo Icons.jsx, luego podremos usar ese objeto 'Icons' para, en conjunto con la propiedad 'icon' del JSON y la sintaxis de corchetes acceder a las distintas rutas, nota que las referencias de Icons.jsx deben coincidir con la propiedad "icon" del archivo JSON.

FetchJson.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import data from "../assets/data/menu.json";
import MenuItem from "./MenuItem";
import * as Icons from './Icons' // obtenemos todos los exports en forma de objeto

function FetchJson() {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((data, i) => {
        return (
          <div key={i}>
            <MenuItem
              icon={Icons[data.icon]} // accedemos a las propiedades de Icons con la notacion de brackets
              title={data.title}
            />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
export default FetchJson;
```

De todas maneras si el icono no se encuentra podremos poner uno por defecto, importando la ruta al icono notfound.svg y pasarlo como valor por defecto de la prop 'icon' en el componente 'MenuItem'

MenuItem.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { notfound } from './Icons';

function MenuItem({ icon = notfound, title = 'title'}) {
  return (
    <div title={title}>
        {title}
        <img src={icon}  style={{height: "24px", width: "24px"}}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MenuItem;
```

componente raiz App.jsx

```
import FetchJson from './components/Fetchjson'
    
function App() {
  
  return (
    <div>
      <FetchJson></FetchJson>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

[image: archivos]

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, esto es algo que ya comprobe, pero al pasar los SVG en una etiqueta <img> no me carga las imagenes, por eso en mi MenuItem le paso por prop el componente Icon, de hecho yo los SVG los importo como componente en mi Icons.jsx
export {ReactComponent as FuelMenuSvg} from "../assets/img/FuelMenuButton.svg";
Por ejemplo

Comment: quizas deberias agregar ese Icons.jsx a la pregunta, sino no entiendo porque a mi me las trae bien por ejemplo, el error debera estar en otro lado